# Get most recent date based on Group By in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a movie table with over 100 different movies, shown below on PostgreSQL:

[image]

I want the name of each **most-recent released** movie, ***according to EACH GENRE***.

How do I get the following output below in PostgreSQL?

[image]

Comment: Empty result? What a strange requirement.

Comment: Just a work order for the sweatshop. I guess that is just accepted.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate after [23,765,105 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)? [662,134 SQL questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [170,236 PostgreSQL questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function such as `DENSE_RANK()` and filter by returning value equals to **1** like in the following one

```
SELECT Genre, Movie_Name 
  FROM
  (
   SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Genre ORDER BY Released_Date DESC) AS dr
    FROM t
  ) tt
 WHERE dr = 1
```

where

- `PARTITION BY` means `GROUP BY`
- `DESC`endingly `ORDER`ing `BY` means to get the latest ones
- `DENSE_RANK()` function keeps ties of Released_Dates(*equal date
  values per each group*) unlike to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT ON` to get distinct genres. The `ORDER BY` will give you the most recent one for each genre.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Genre) Movie_Name, Genre, Released_Date 
FROM movie_table m
ORDER BY Genre, Released_Date DESC
```